# Android: notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android

Hello guys I am doing the delete function in my project and it seems that the `notifyDataSetChanged` is not working. I've already done some research about this but I don't quiet understand

here is my code in onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_dropped_student);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        subj_code = preferences.getString("code", "UNKNOWN");
        subj_code_lab = preferences.getString("code_lab", "UNKNOWN");

        studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        arrayAdapter = new StudAdapter(this, stud_List);
        mylistView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        new LoadStudent().execute();
        mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final String studentId = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.stud_id))).getText().toString();
                final String studentName = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.studName))).getText().toString();
                class AttemptGetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
                    String code = subj_code.toString();
                    String id = studentId;
                    String stud_name = studentName;

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewDroppedStudent.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("In Progress...");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                        String url = null;
                        try {
                            url = "http://192.168.22.3/MobileClassRecord/undroppedStudent.php?stud_id="+ URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8")+"&subj_code="+ URLEncoder.encode(subj_code, "UTF-8");
                        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        List<NameValuePair> mList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stud_id", id));
                        mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subj_code", code));

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", mList);
                        Log.d("Undrop Student", jsonObject.toString());
                        try {
                            verify = jsonObject.getString("Message");
                            return verify;
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                        super.onPostExecute(s);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        if (s != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), verify, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                final MaterialDialog materialDialog = new MaterialDialog(ViewDroppedStudent.this);
                materialDialog.setTitle("Undrop Student");
                materialDialog.setMessage("Name: " + studentName);
                materialDialog.setPositiveButton("UNDROP", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        materialDialog.dismiss();
                        new AttemptGetData().execute();
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        materialDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                materialDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried to put this  arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onPostExecute()

Comment: I am not sure but Try to call this method(notifyDataSetChanged) in onPostExecute(). Because you are calling this method after asyntask.

Comment: hi sir @MohammadAbuQauod no luck :(

Comment: I give up :( maybe I'll just refresh the activity from itself, btw thanks for all of your response :)

Comment: @CallMeJeo send me your project or at least your stoppable code as project and i'll do my best to solve it for you, don't give up.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in onPostExecute method

```
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                        super.onPostExecute(s);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        if (s != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), verify, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove perticular data from your `stud_List`
2. put `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onPostExecute()`

It is possible that sometime notifiDatasetChanged not works with custom adapter.

you can create custom method in your adapter like below :

```
public void refresh(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list)
{
    this.list=list; //replace this.list with your adapter list variable.
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

call it in onPostExecute()

```
arrayAdapter.refresh(stud_List);
```

Comment: hello sir please see my full code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRtxsi3HCNWSjRRZXVTRU54NjQ/view?usp=sharing
I still quiet understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `asynctask` runs asyncronously so when you call execute() on `asynctask` it will run in a parallel thread while the execution of main thread continues. So your `notifydatasetchanged()` is getting called even before your `asynctask()` is finished. So call `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onPostExecute()`